# Example for an operator that is strictly monotone but not maximally monotone (or the other way)

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis, monotone-operator-theory

While the definition of strictly monotone = nowhere constant operators seems intuitive, I find it hard to picture in which way maximal monotone operators ($\forall (u,u') \in X \times X', \langle u'-v', u-v \rangle \geqslant 0 \forall (v,v') \in G(A) \Rightarrow (u,u') \in G(A)$) differ; I would much appreciate a clarifying example!

Answer (score 1):

The operator

$$\mathbb{R} \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto 
\begin{cases}\{x\}, &\text{if $x\neq 0$;}\\ \\ 
\varnothing, &\text{if $x\neq 0$;}
\end{cases}
$$
is strictly monotone, but not maximally monotone.

The operator
$$\mathbb{R} \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \{0\}
$$
is maximally monotone, but not strictly monotone.